# AutoLISP code assistance: Removing offset operation

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I'm working on an AutoLISP script in AutoCAD that involves offsetting polylines, and I'm encountering issues with the offseting part. However, I've decided that I want to remove the offset operation entirely from the code.

Here are the key points:

1. I have a function named FM_RM3 that is intended to offset polylines
   based on a specified layer and direction.
2. I've realized that I no longer need the offset operation and would
   like to modify the code to work directly with the original
   coordinates of the polylines.
3. I'm seeking assistance in removing the offset-related code from the
   FM_RM3 function. Any help or guidance on which specific lines to
   remove for this purpose would be highly appreciated.

```
(defun c:FM_RM3
    (/ ss sset layer echo temp offdist direction n en ed pt LL UR MP minpoint maxpoint
       area1 area2 newpoly vtx ucsFlag enExtr)

;start offset multi polylines----------

(command "._undo" "_begin")

;verwijderen bestaande polylines op specifieke layer "*":
(setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "*LWPOLYLINE") (8 . "0"))))
(command "erase" ss "")


;selecteren polylines op specifieke layer:
(setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "*LWPOLYLINE") (8 . "00---0--FM-RUIMTEDEFV")))) 

;bepalen naar welke layer offset "*":
(or (tblsearch "LAYER" "0") (command "_.LAYER" "_New" "0" "")) (setq LAYER "0") 

  ;afstand van offset fixed:
  (setq offdist 5)
  ;richting van offset fixed:
  (setq direction "Out")

  (if (= direction "Out")
      (progn  ;;OUT
        (setq n 0)
        (setq pt (list (1+ (car (getvar 'extmax)))
                       (1+ (cadr (getvar 'extmax)))))
        (repeat (sslength ss)
          (setq en (ssname ss n))
          (if (not (= 8 (logand 8 (cdr (assoc 70 (entget en))))));no 3Dp
            (progn
            (command "._offset" offdist en pt "")
            (SetQ ENTITY (EntLast)
                  ENTITY (EntGet ENTITY)
                  ENTITY (SubSt (Cons 8 LAYER) (Assoc 8 ENTITY) ENTITY)
            )
            (EntMod ENTITY)
            )
            )
          (setq n (1+ n))
          )
        )

      (progn  ;;IN
        (setq n 0)
          (repeat (sslength ss)
            (setq ucsFlag nil)
            (setq en (ssname ss n))
            (setq ed (entget en))
            (if (not (= 8 (logand 8 (cdr (assoc 70 ed)))))
                (progn
                  (setq enExtr (cadddr (assoc 210 ed)))
                  (if (not (= enExtr (caddr (trans '( 0.0 0.0 1.0) 0 1))))
                    (progn
                      (setq elev
                         (cond
                           ((= enType "LWPOLYLINE")
                            (cdr (assoc 38 ed))
                           )
                           (T
                            (caddr (cdr (assoc 10 ed)))
                           )
                         );cond
                       )
                      (command "._ucs" "_3point"
                        (trans (list 0.0 0.0 elev) en 1)
                        (trans (list 1.0 0.0 elev) en 1)
                        (trans (list 0.0 1.0 elev) en 1)
                        )
                      (setq ucsFlag T)
                    )
                  )

                  (setq obj (vlax-ename->vla-object en))
                  (vla-getboundingbox obj 'minpoint 'maxpoint)
                  (setq LL (trans (vlax-safearray->list minpoint) 0 1)
                        UR (trans (vlax-safearray->list maxpoint) 0 1)
                        MP (list (/ (+ (car LL) (car UR)) 2.0)
                                 (/ (+ (cadr LL) (cadr UR)) 2.0))
                        )
                  (command "._area" "_object" en)
                  (setq area1 (getvar 'area))
     ;;MP is approximate centroid of polyline - test if in fact inside
                  (command "._offset" offdist en MP "")
                  (SetQ ENTITY (EntLast)
                        ENTITY (EntGet ENTITY)
                        ENTITY (SubSt (Cons 8 LAYER) (Assoc 8 ENTITY) ENTITY)
                  )
                  (EntMod ENTITY)
                  (setq newpoly (entlast))
                  (command "._area" "_object" newpoly)
                  (setq area2 (getvar 'area))
     ;;if new polyline is outside the original, offset it
     ;;twice the original distance in the other direction
                  (if (> area2 area1)
                    (progn
                      (setq vtx (entnext (entnext en)))
                      (setq pt
                        (trans (cdr (assoc 10 (entget vtx))) 0 1))
                      (command "._offset" (* 2.0 offdist) newpoly pt "")
                      (SetQ ENTITY (EntLast)
                            ENTITY (EntGet ENTITY)
                            ENTITY (SubSt (Cons 8 LAYER) (Assoc 8 ENTITY) ENTITY)
                      )
                      (EntMod ENTITY)

                      (entdel newpoly)
                      )
                     )
                    )
                  )
              (if ucsFlag (command "._ucs" "_p"))
              (setq n (1+ n))
            );;repeat
          )
      )


;einde offset multi polylines----------



;start export coordinaten----------

  ;selecteren polylines op specifieke layer:
  (setq sset (ssget "X" '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE") (8 . "0")))) 


(if sset

   (progn

     (setq itm 0 num (sslength sset))

     ;opslaan als met dialoog:
     ;(setq fn (getfiled "Point Export File" "" "txt" 1))
     ;direct opslaan in directory van dwg en met naam van de tekening:
     (setq fn (strcat (getvar 'DWGPREFIX) (vl-string-subst "txt" "dwg" (getvar 'DWGNAME))))
     


     (if (/= fn nil)

       (progn

         (setq fh (open fn "w"))

         (while (< itm num)

         (setq hnd (ssname sset itm))

           (setq ent (entget hnd))

           (setq obj (cdr (assoc 0 ent)))

           (cond

             ((= obj "POINT")

               (setq pnt (cdr (assoc 10 ent)))

               (setq pnt (trans pnt 0 1));;**CAB

               (princ (strcat (rtos (car pnt) 2 8) ","

                               (rtos (cadr pnt) 2 8) ","

                               (rtos (caddr pnt) 2 8)) fh)

               (princ "\n" fh)

             )

             ((= obj "LWPOLYLINE")


         ; ID hyperlink;            
         ;(princ (geturl hnd) fh)
         ; ID d.m.v. handle;
          (princ (cdr (assoc 5 ENTITY)) fh)
              (princ "\n" fh)

               (if (= (cdr (assoc 38 ent)) nil)

                 (setq elv 0.0)

                 (setq elv (cdr (assoc 38 ent)))

               )

               (foreach rec ent

                 (if (= (car rec) 10)

                   (progn

                     (setq pnt (cdr rec))

                     (setq pnt (trans pnt 0 1));;**CAB

                     (princ (strcat (rtos (car pnt) 2 8) ","

                                     (rtos (cadr pnt) 2 8) ","

                                    (rtos elv 2 8)) fh)

                     (princ "\n" fh)

                   )

                 )

               )

             )

             (t nil)

           )

           (setq itm (1+ itm))

         )

        (close fh)

       )

     )

   )

)

;einde export coordinaten----------

;verwijderen bestaande polylines op specifieke layer "*":
(setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "*LWPOLYLINE") (8 . "0"))))
(command "erase" ss "")


(princ)
);;defun

(defun c:ompnl ()
  (c:offsetmultiplepolylinestonewlayer)
  )

(princ "\nFM_RM3 loaded. Type FM_RM3 to run.")
;(princ "\nOffsetMultiplePolylinestoNewLayer loaded. Type OMPNL to run.")
(princ)
(vl-load-com)
```

Comment: Please refer to [ask] for suggestions to improve the question, if not already, consider taking the [tour].

Comment: (!= AutoLisp CommonLisp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove the part between

```
;afstand van offset fixed:
```

and

```
;einde offset multi polylines----------
```

and you'll have what you need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).